# Copy the Entities with basepoint using Ctrl + C in Autocad using C#

Tags: c#, autocad

Hi friends,

```
         I have some trouble while copy the entities using Ctrl+C in autocad. While i press ctrl + C it just copy to clipboard in autocad and it's take base point as 0,0,0.But i need to copy the entities with our specified  base point. Is there any other way to do this.
```

Comment: Do you mean create a copy of an entity with a specified displacement??

Comment: If you're trying ctrl+c, you're not doing it in C#, right???
If manual operation can be done: use the copy command in Autocad prompt.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the _COPYBASE command instead (Ctrl-Shift-C is the default hotkey).

Answer (score 2):

Via C# using the `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common` reference:

```
double[] BasePoint = new double[] { 0, 0, 0}; //or any point you like
double[] DesiredPoint = new double[] { 45,234,2345} ;//or any point you like

IAcadEntity Ent = AGivenEntity.Copy();
Ent.Move(BasePoint, DesiredPoint);
```